# What is the value of default(IEnumerable<T>)?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ienumerable, default

**What is the value of** `default(IEnumerable<T>)` **in .NET 4.0, C# ?** (Pretty much straightforward)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
null
```

[default Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> will be null for reference types and zero for value types.

`IEnumerable` is not value type, so result will be `null`

Comment: The page you've linked to is unfortunately poor: "Given a variable t of a parameterized type T, the statement t = null is only valid if T is a reference type" - that fails to take `Nullable<T>` into account. (The default value for any nullable value type is also the null value for that type.) The page mentions `Nullable<T>` later on, so the author was clearly aware of it...

Answer (score 4):

It is null because it is a reference type.